# Excel VBA : Save file in the same location as macro

Tags: excel, vba

How do I save the result of the macro i.e. and excel file in the same folder where the macro file is located ?

I am trying to use the below code :

```
CurDir
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:="Accenture.xlsx" FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
```

Comment: hi maciej.. I am trying to use ur suggested line.. but that does not work :(

Comment: whrere is your result in the same macro workbook? or another workbook?

Comment: Maciej didn't change the code, just editted the formatting so that its properly displayed here

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:= ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Accenture.xlsx" ...
```

For further details, please see:
[Workbook.Path Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.path.aspx)
[How to: Get and Set the Default File Path for Workbooks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tf9k1sdd(v=vs.90).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "dummy.xlsm"
```